# Monkey Patching a String Python

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am working on a python project and below is what I have:

```
mystring= 'Hello work'
```

and I want to write a function that replaces `k` with a `m` some thing like below:

```
def replace_alpha(string):
    return string.replace('k', 'm') # returns Hello worm
```

I wanted to use `Monkey Patching` on a `string` such that I can use it the below way:

```
string = 'Hello work'
string = string.replace_alpha()
print(string)   # prints Hello worm
```

instead of:

```
string = replace_alpha(string)
```

is this possible? Can I use monkey patching with a built-in rather can I extent the `__builtins__`?

Comment: That's not monkey patching. Monkey patching is the modification of an object from a different scope.

Comment: @hspandher op stated that he doesnt want to touch `__builtins__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible with [forbiddenfruit](https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit) library:

```
from forbiddenfruit import curse

def replace_alpha(string):
    return string.replace('k', 'm')

curse(str, "replace_alpha", replace_alpha)

s = 'Hello work'
print(s.replace_alpha())
```

Comment: The wording of this library is beautiful :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible so easily. You cannot set attributes of immutable `str` instances or the built-in `str` class. Without that capability, it is tough change their behaviour. You can, however, subclass `str`:

```
class PatchStr(str):
  def replace_alpha(self):
    return self.replace('k', 'm')

string = PatchStr('hello work')
string = string.replace_alpha()
string
# 'hello worm'
```

I don't think you can get much closer.

Comment: `string` remains `"hello work"`, however.

Comment: @AdamSmith which it (the str object the method is called on) does in the OP's code, too. Of course, you have to reassign the return value.

Comment: That's not how I understand the requested end state.

Comment: @AdamSmith `string` is just a variable name. The behaviour is the one stated by the OP.  `string = string.replace_alpha()` in the original post indicates that they are not expecting to mutate the object.